# std::get content from std::variant using an element from an integer array as targeted type in std::variant

Tags: c++, dynamic, variant

I have a integer array to retrieve content in std::variant. But it fails compilation, error message `No matching function to call 'get'`. Can you explain why, and suggest working solution to achieve same purpose?

```cpp
using my_type = std::variant<int, float, bool>;
constexpr int[] expected_types = {2,2,2,2};
 

bool validate(std::vector<my_type> input) {
  bool rst;
  if (input.size() != 4) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    rst = rst || std::get<my_type[i]>(input[i]);
  }
  return rst;
}
```

Here is more context. Class A, B, C both implements the interface `bool foo(std::vector<my_type> input)`. But class A's input is in the format of {int, int, bool}, class B's input is in the format of {int, int, float}, class C's input is in the format of {bool,bool}. expected_types in each class saves its own types in input vector. Then std::get<expected_types[i]> is used to access element in the input vector. Can you suggest an clear and elegant pattern to fit my case?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `std::get<expected_types[i]>`?

Comment: What is `constexpr int[] expected_types = {2, 2, 2, 2};` supposed to mean?

Comment: There are multiple issues here. The variant has three possible values. The loop iterates four times. Does that make sense to you? A variant has one of several possible values, by definition. That's what a variant is, this one has either an `int`, a `float`, or a `bool`. Only one of them. So what does checking the variant three, or four, different times does? Finally, template parameters must be specified at compile time, not run time. As Mr. Spock would say: none of this is logical. Before getting this programming assignment, these concepts must've been explained to you. What was unclear?

Comment: `get()` is a template function. You can't pass runtime variables to template arguments. So this approach will never work

Comment: @TedLyngmo Lyngmo The idea is class A and class B both implements the interface `bool foo(std::vector<my_type> input)`. But class A's input is in the format of {int, int, bool}, class B's input is in the format of {int, int, float}. std::get<expected_types[i]>(input) helps me to get corresponding values in class A or class B. My confustion/question is std::get<expected_types[i]>(input) will generate compilation error, but std::get<expected_types[0]>(input) won't. Because expected_types is already a constexpr, why it still can't be compiled?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi Remy, thanks for pointing the error. But the expected_types is constexpr, so this is known in the compile time. Can you suggest a solution on this?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hi Sam, here is more context. Class A, B, C both implements the interface bool foo(std::vector<my_type> input). But class A's input is in the format of {int, int, bool}, class B's input is in the format of {int, int, float}, class C's input is in the format of {bool,bool}. expected_types in each class saves its own types in input vector. Then std::get<expected_types[i]> is used to access element in the input vector. Can you suggest a clear implementation to achieve this in C++?

Comment: @Biear Then I assume you mean `constexpr int expected_types[] = {2,2,2,2};` and `std::get<expected_types[i]>(input[i])` right? Not that that's going to work either, but it is still more correct :-) Also, if you are to _validate_ that the `vector` of `variant` is holding the expected types, should you really use a logical `OR` instead of a logical `AND`?

Comment: What do you mean by _"Then std::get<expected_types[i]> is used to access element in the input vector."_? Are you trying to validate that the `vector` of `variant` contrans the correct types to do you want to access the values somehow?

Comment: I finally understood what was asked here. None of the answers here addressed it directly -- a convenient way to define types to retrieve from each one of the values. The lack of clarity was exacerbated by fake code, with liberal sprinkling of "my-this" and "my-that" that clouded the real question, rather than real code. This is usually done with a combination of `std::index_sequence`, specialization, and some helper templates. It's always messy, and convoluted, but takes up a lot of verbiage. But, it's doable.

Comment: @Biear "*the `expected_types` is `constexpr`, so this is known in the compile time*" - but `i` isn't. The array may be `constexpr`, but you are iterating through it at runtime. Templates can only be instantiated at compile-time, so `std::get<expected_types[i]>` can't work when `i` is a loop counter at runtime.

Comment: @Biear If none of the answers answer your question you probably need to update the question to provide details and clarity. If you combine it with some examples and the output you expect from your function it'll be a lot easier to make an answer that provides you with the information you need.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik
Hi Sam, could you share your code snippet of this question? Thanks!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Re: _"None of the answers here addressed it directly"_ - What does _"it"_ refer to? On the surface, it looks like your C++17 answer is very similar to my C++20 answer so I'm curious about what I missed.

Comment: That was addressing the two answers that were posted previously, @TedLyngmo. I left the question and came back to it after finally realizing what the OP was trying to  ask, that the earlier answers missed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Aha, I see. Thanks for clearing that up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your `validate` function correctly, it's supposed to validate that the `vector<variant<int, float, bool>>` ...

1. Has the correct length for the type `A`, `B` or `C`.
2. Contains the `variant` types indicated by the `variant` indices in`A::expected_types[]`, `B::expected_types[]` or `C::expected_types[]`.

It could then take the type it's testing the `vector` for (`A`, `B` or `C`) as a template parameter and use the `variant::index()` to check which type the individual `variant`s holds in the `vector`.

Combine it with a fold over `&&` (since you want all to be `true`) and you'll get:

```cpp
template<class T>
bool validate(const std::vector<my_type>& input) {
    if (input.size() != std::size(T::expected_types))  return false;

    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        // fold over && :
        return (... && (input[Is].index() == T::expected_types[Is]));
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::size(T::expected_types)>());
}
```

If you *really* want to `std::get` the `expected_types` from the `vector` and use logical `OR`, that could be done in a similar way, but folding over `||`:

```cpp
template <class T>
bool get_bool(const std::vector<my_type>& input) {
    if (not validate<T>(input)) return false; // use the validation function above

    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        // fold over ||
        return (... || (std::get<T::expected_types[Is]>(input[Is])));
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::size(T::expected_types)>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GK7The6fh)

Comment: Thank you Ted! Your solution is neat, I need to learn this solution! For my use case, Class A, B, C both implements the interface bool foo(std::vector<my_type> input). But class A's input is in the format of {int, int, bool}, class B's input is in the format of {int, int, float}, class C's input is in the format of {bool,bool}. Do you have a better idea to solve implement this elegantly? Is there a better solution than using std::vector<std::variant<int, float, bool>> at input argument?

Comment: @Biear The free function templates in my answer can be used by A, B and C to implement the interface. You could also put the interface implementation in a CRTP base or use runtime polymorphism. Can you please update the question to clearly show what the interface is supposed to look like and what you expect from it if it's not clear how the two function templates I made should be used?

Comment: Hi @Ted Lyngmo, geart thanks for answering my question. It takes me several days to understand your code. I just switched from java developer to c++ area.  A more general question coming from this. I have another function `void record(vector<my_type> input)` to implement. It takes a input vector, and do something using contents from that vector.
```
class A {
  constexpr int[] expected_types = {2,0,1,2};
  void record(vector<my_type> input) {
   std::get<expected_types[0]>(input[0]); // Is there more formal way to retrieve the contents?
  }
}
```
Runnable snippet shorturl.at/erY17

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I closed this one, and opened a new question. Could you take a look at the new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370505?

Answer (score 2):

Since the function [get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) expects either a type or a compile-time constant as an index, your approach will not work.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to modify your function, to make it a function template.

Then, when calling your “validate” function, you can hand in the index value of the bool as a compile-time constant template parameter.

Your program would then look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using my_type = std::variant<int, float, bool>;
constexpr size_t intPart = 0;
constexpr size_t floatPart = 1;
constexpr size_t boolPart = 2;

template <std::size_t I>
bool validate(std::vector<my_type> input) {
    bool rst{};
    if (input.size() != 4) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        rst = rst || std::get<I>(input[i]);
    }
    return rst;
}
int main() {
    std::vector<my_type> boolData(4);
    boolData[0].emplace<boolPart>(false);
    boolData[1].emplace<boolPart>(false);
    boolData[2].emplace<boolPart>(true);
    boolData[3].emplace<boolPart>(false);

    bool result = validate<boolPart>(boolData);

    std::cout << "Result = " << std::boolalpha << result << '\n';
}
```

If you later would need to extend your validate function to handle also the other types of your `std::variant`, you could do this with variadic templates and `constexpr if`

Please feedback, if this is solution is sufficient for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::variant::index` allows to achieve goal in nice way:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool validate(std::vector<my_type> input, const T& expectedTypes)
{
    if (input.size() != std::size(expectedTypes)) {
        return false;
    }
    bool rst = true;
    auto it = std::begin(input);
    for (auto expectedType : expectedTypes) {
        rst = rst && (it->index() == expectedType);
        ++it;
    }
    return rst;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G9aMfWfEn

Answer (score 1):

`my_type` isn't an array so `my_type[i]` doesn't make sense.

I'm guessing that `std::get<my_type[i]>(input[i])` was meant to be `std::get<expected_types[i]>(input[i])`? That won't work either as `i` isn't a compile time constant so can't be used as a template expression.

One workaround would be to unroll your `for` loop:

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <array>

using my_type = std::variant<int, float, bool>;
constexpr std::array<int,4> expected_types = {2,2,2,2};
 

bool validate(std::vector<my_type> input) {
  bool rst = false;
  if (input.size() != 4) {
    return false;
  }
  rst = rst || std::get<expected_types[0]>(input[0]);
  rst = rst || std::get<expected_types[1]>(input[1]);
  rst = rst || std::get<expected_types[2]>(input[2]);
  rst = rst || std::get<expected_types[3]>(input[3]);
  return rst;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long i = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long>(nullptr)    ;
}
```

If what you're actually trying to do is check that the types match the expected ones then you can just use the `index` method:

```
bool validate(std::vector<my_type> input) {
  bool rst = false;
  if (input.size() != 4) {
    return false;
  }
  for (std::size_t i=0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    rst = rst || expected_types[i] == input[i].index();
  }
  return rst;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alan, 
> Did you mean std::get<expected_types[i]>
Yes, I want to use std::get<expected_types[i]> to get class specific typed values. For example, classA has expected_types{1,1,2}, classB has expected_types{0,0,1}. I want std::get<expected_types[0]> gets an float in classA and int in classB.

Answer (score 1):

you can only access a variant by specify the Type or an index like:

```
std::get<int>(variant)
std::get<0>(variant)
```

But your problem to access the variant from the vector in the loop without specifying the type or index explicitly can be handled using the visitor (we don't even need another variable to keep the index to type of variant in the vector)

visitor structure can be used to perform the logical or operation on the value of the variant and save the result which can be later returned.

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using my_type = std::variant<int, float, bool>;
//constexpr int[] expected_types = {2,2,2,2};

struct logicalOrOperationVisitor
{
    bool rst;
    
    logicalOrOperationVisitor(bool b) : rst(b) { }
    
    void operator()(int &i)
    {
        rst = rst || i;
    }
    
    void operator()(float &f)
    {
        rst = rst || f;
    }
    
    void operator()(bool &b)
    {
        rst = rst || b;
    }
};


bool validate(std::vector<my_type> input) {
  logicalOrOperationVisitor orRst(false);
  
  if (input.size() != 4) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    //rst = rst || std::get<my_type[i]>(input[i]);
    std::visit(orRst, input[i]);
  }
  return orRst.rst;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, this kind of a validation is a pain, and requires a bunch of verbiage, including specialization.

This uses C++17 syntax, which, I think is reasonable in the year 2023. This also validates that each variant in the vector is, actually, the correct type, and fails validation if not. This wasn't made explicit in the question, but I'm fairly certain that it was implied.

```
#include <utility>
#include <variant>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using my_type = std::variant<int, float, bool>;
constexpr size_t expected_types[] = {0, 2, 2, 2};

template<typename T>
struct do_validate;

template<size_t ...N>
struct do_validate<std::index_sequence<N...>> {

    static bool validate(const std::vector<my_type> &input)
    {
        if (input.size() != sizeof...(N))
            return false;

        return ( (expected_types[N] ==
              input[N].index() &&
              std::get<expected_types[N]>(input[N])) || ...);
    }
};

bool validate(const std::vector<my_type> &input)
{
    return do_validate<std::make_index_sequence<std::size(expected_types)>>
        ::validate(input);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<my_type> n{{
            my_type{ std::in_place_index<0>, 1},
            my_type{ std::in_place_index<2>, false},
            my_type{ std::in_place_index<2>, false},
            my_type{ std::in_place_index<2>, false}
        }};

    std::cout << validate(n) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```