# Elegant way to use std::get to access data in std::variant

Tags: c++, dynamic, variadic-templates, variant

I'm a new C++ user from the Java world. Here is the context: Different class needs to implement `foo()` function from `Base` class. But this function has different combination of `my_type` as input. I'm feeling using something like `std::get<2>(input[1])` everywhere in the code is not easy to read and understand. Is there a elegant way to access content in an std::variant? Demo https://shorturl.at/tLQV3

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
using my_type = std::variant<int, float, bool>;

struct Base {
  virtual void foo(std::vector<my_type>) = 0;
  virtual ~Base() {};
};

struct B : Base {
  static constexpr int kMetricRawDataTypes[] = {2,2,2,2};
  void foo(std::vector<my_type> input) {
    bool num_0 = std::get<2>(input[0]); // Question1.1 - is there any more elegant way to access the value?
    bool num_1 = std::get<2>(input[1]);  
    bool num_2 = std::get<2>(input[2]);
    bool num_3 = std::get<2>(input[3]);
    std::cout << "input " << num_0 << " " << num_1 << " " << num_2 << " " << num_3 << std::endl;
  }
};

struct A : Base {
  static constexpr int kMetricRawDataTypes[] = {1, 2, 0, 1};
  void foo(std::vector<my_type> input) {
    float num_0 = std::get<1>(input[0]); // Question 1.2 - is there any more elegant way to access the value?
    bool num_1 = std::get<2>(input[1]);  
    int num_2 = std::get<0>(input[2]);
    float num_3 = std::get<1>(input[3]);
    std::cout << "input " << num_0 << " " << num_1 << " " << num_2 << " " << num_3 << std::endl;
  }
};


int main() {
  my_type num1 = 1.0f;
  my_type num2 = true;
  my_type num3 = 5;
  my_type num4 = 3.0f;
  std::vector<my_type> input = {num1, num2, num3, num4};
  A a;
  a.foo(input);
  return 0;
}
```

I feel there should be good solution using template. Please advise!

Comment: It seems you were lucky and the question got reopened again. Miracles do happen :) Have you had a chance to take a look at the answer in the meantime? I'll gladly clarify anything that looks strange or incomprehensible.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks Ted, this looks good to me. I learned a lot from your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the [`validate` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75295170/7582247) in my old answer as input and rewrite it slightly to fit your new class definition. Then to print the contained types, you could fold over `operator,`. To only have to implement `foo` once, you could put that in a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) base for `A` and `B`. I've chosen to make the `validate` function a member of the CRTP base here.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using my_type = std::variant<int, float, bool>;

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo(const std::vector<my_type>& input) const = 0;
};

template<class T>        // A CRTP base for A and B
struct foo_impl : Base {
    bool validate(const std::vector<my_type>& input) const {
        return input.size() == std::size(T::kMetricRawDataTypes)
            && [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
                   // fold over && :
                   return (... && (input[Is].index() ==
                                   T::kMetricRawDataTypes[Is]));
               }(std::make_index_sequence<std::size(T::kMetricRawDataTypes)>());
    }

    void foo(const std::vector<my_type>& input) const override {
        if(validate(input)) {
            std::cout << "input";
            [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
                // fold over , (comma) to print:
                ((std::cout << ' ' <<
                  std::get<T::kMetricRawDataTypes[Is]>(input[Is])),
                  ...);
            }(std::make_index_sequence<std::size(T::kMetricRawDataTypes)>());
            std::cout << '\n';
        } else {
            std::cout << "not valid\n";
        }
    }
};

struct A : foo_impl<A> { // inherit with `A` as a template parameter
    static constexpr int kMetricRawDataTypes[] = {1, 2, 0, 1};
};

struct B : foo_impl<B> { // inherit with `B` as a template parameter
    static constexpr int kMetricRawDataTypes[] = {2, 2, 2, 2};
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6eerPjn9G)